# Kendo Combo Box onkeypress Event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, combobox, keypress, kendo-combobox

I'm having a trouble on handling large data on combo box cause it returns at least **16,000 records** I tried this method `JsonReturnResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;` but my browser still hangs up. Now what I want to do is to trigger the query when the **User** presses `Enter`.

Here's my code :

```
<script>
function onSelectCAO() {
                     var AccountName = $("#ChildAccountCode").val();
                     $("#account_name").data("kendoComboBox").value(AccountName);
                     document.getElementById("text_AcccountName").value = AccountName;

                 }
</script>

<input type="text" id="text_AcccountName" name="text_AcccountName" style="width:80%;" hidden="hidden"/>

@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()

                                .Name("ChildAccountCode")
                                .DataTextField("ChildAccountCode1")
                                .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                                .MinLength(3)
                                .Placeholder("Select ChildAccountCode")
                                .DataValueField("AccountName1")
                                .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width: 200px;" })
                                .Events(e =>
                                    {
                                        e.Change("onSelectCAO");
                                    })
                                                    .DataSource(source =>
                                                                {
                                                                    source.Read(read =>
                                                                        {
                                                                            read.Action("ddlChildAccountCode", "Dropdowns");
                                                                        });
                                                                })                                                                                       
             )
```

What I want to accomplish is when User presses `Enter` it will only return results base on what User input it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved my problems. So here's my solution I set the `AutoBind` into `false` and set the **Parameter** on my `DataSource` as filter or condition on my query

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()

                                .Name("ChildAccountCode")
                                .DataTextField("ChildAccountCode")
                                .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                                .MinLength(3)
                                .Placeholder("Select ChildAccountCode")
                                .DataValueField("AccountName")
                                .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width: 200px;" })
                                .AutoBind(false)
                                .Events(e =>
                                    {
                                        e.Change("onSelectCAO");
                                    })
                                                    .DataSource(source =>
                                                                {
                                                                    source.Read(read =>
                                                                        {
                                                                            read.Action("ddlChildAccountCode", "Dropdowns").Data("AccountCodeParameter");
                                                                        });
                                                                })                                                                                       
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

inside script.

```
$("#DropDownID").data("kendoComboBox").input.keydown(function (e) {
console.log("KeyPressed");
  console.log(e.keyCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I strictly advise you to get data to combobox by ServerFilteringTrue attribute of Kendo.
Because 16000 records is so high.

You can use text filtering on Kendo with contains and in Business side
You can filter by name and id with the text you enter to combobox.

the filter method in jquery can be like

```
function filterByText() {
    var mainText = $("#DropDownID").data("kendoComboBox").input.val();
    return {
        text: mainText
    };
}
```

And kendo combobox be like

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SomeModelId)</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m.SomeModelId)
                 .DataTextField("ChildAccountCode")
                 .DataValueField("Id")
                 .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%", id = "ChildAccountCode", data_value_primitive = "true", required = "required", validationMessage = "Select code" })
                 .Placeholder("Select some code")
                 .Filter("contains")
                 .AutoBind(true)
                 .Suggest(false)
                 .DataSource(source =>
                 {
                     source.Read(read =>
                     {
                         read.Action("ddlChildAccountCode", "DropDowns").Data("filterByText");
                     })
                     .ServerFiltering(true);
                 }).AutoBind(true)
        )
    </div>
</div>
```

For example in your controller if the text parameter length is smaller than 3, you can not fill anything to combobox, so it will make DB calls less cost.

I hope that will be useful to you